# ts-node doesn't seem to be picking up typings from typeRoots

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I'm using typescript for webpack config.

My tsconfig looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "esnext",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "typings",
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src", "typings"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "../../../node_modules"
  ]
}
```

then in my typings/index.d.ts

```
import webpack from 'webpack';

declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      NODE_ENV: 'development' | 'production' | 'none';
      PROFILING?: string;
      SOURCE_MAP?: webpack.Options.Devtool;
      IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT: string;
      KIND: 'lib' | 'app' | 'shell';
      PUBLIC_PATH?: string;
      MAX_ASSET_SIZE: string;
      MAX_ENTRY_POINT_SIZE: string;
      OPTIMIZE?: 'optimize';
    }
  }
}

declare module 'dotenv-extended' {
  interface dotEnvExtended {
    load: (options: Partial<{
      encoding: string,
      silent: boolean,
      path: string,
      defaults: string,
      schema: string,
      errorOnMissing: boolean,
      errorOnExtra: boolean,
      errorOnRegex: boolean,
      includeProcessEnv: boolean,
      assignToProcessEnv: boolean,
      overrideProcessEnv: boolean
    }>) => void
  }
}

export {}
```

I'm using VS code and it seems to be picking up my typings just fine
[image: vsCode picking up typings as "production" | "development" | "none"]

However, when running actual build ts-node seems to be using `[key: string]: string | undefined;` from global.d.ts

I'm running build like this `yarn cross-env TS_NODE_PROJECT=\"../dev-tools/tsconfig.json\" webpack --config ../dev-tools/src/webpack.config.ts`

Comment: You're mixing a lot of things up. Your `typings/index.ts` doesn't belong under `typeRoots`. It's really a part of your source code and should be treated as such

Comment: @AluanHaddad, thanks for commenting. Could you explain this a little bit? I'd say it shouldn't be in `  "include": ["src", "typings"],`, yes. However, I'd expect typings to be picked up from typeroots

Comment: it turns out https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12222#issuecomment-260417733